# JTS Geometry - Applying a buffer

Tags: geospatial, jts

I am trying to apply a buffer of 1000 meters to a polygon shape in JTS Topology Suite. I have identified the method to do it(see link below), but I am not sure what the unit is for the distance parameter on the buffer method.

[JTS geometry buffer method](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html#buffer%28double%29)

Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The distance unit, of course, has the same unit as your coordinates.

If your coordinates are in meters, then distance is in meters, too.